# Deduce that a category is a topos (and locally cartesian closed) from a dense subcategory of powers of one object

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

I am trying to understand the paper [Classical Lambda Calculus in Modern Dress](https://arxiv.org/abs/1211.5762). On page 7, it states

> Proposition 2.9 shows inter alia that the products of the universal are dense, and so familiar arguments allow one to deduce more structure.
> Proposition 2.11 PT is a topos; in particular it is locally cartesian closed.

I believe this means that the subcategory consisting of the objects $ T^m $ for all $ m $ is dense in the category $ PT $, and that we can deduce from this that $ PT $ is a topos (and then from this that it is locally cartesian closed, and therefore has exponentials).

However, I cannot see how one would easily deduce that $ PT $ is a topos, from the fact that we have this dense subcategory. I asked chatGPT, and it mentioned that the dense subcategory can maybe help construct exponentials, which helps in proving that $ PT $ is a topos, but that is the wrong way around.

Can someone shed a bit of light on the issue: what would be the main parts of the "familiar arguments"?

Comment: Perhaps the simplest approach would be to use Proposition 2.13 of the paper, where it is observed that $P\mathcal{T}$ is a presheaf category, which are [well known to be toposes](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/category+of+presheaves).

Comment: Right, so perhaps it’s about finding a dense small subcategory of tiny objects, which precisely characterizes presheaf toposes.

Comment: @KevinArlin Does such a dense small subcategory characterize presheaf toposes in general, or are you suggesting that in this case it maybe is possible to prove this in this way?

Comment: There is a [characterisation of presheaf categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/atomic+category) in this manner, though I suspect a direct proof would be simpler, because the definitions involved are completely concrete.

Comment: @varkor Thank you! Someone explained to me that Proposition 2.9 shows that we can view objects in PT as presheaves (I had not looked at the definition of presheaf before), and that therefore this is a topos.